# Laravel subscription implementation without Stripe

Tags: php, laravel, subscription

I have a Laravel project that users must subscribe to one of our plans and each plan has its own specific features, like http://busy.io subscription system.
As far as billing services like **Stripe** and **Braintree** do not support **IRR (ريال)** currency, and also, **PayPal** and **Visa** are *not* available in Iran (that does not mean we don't have online billing service, we have our local banking system), I have to implement users subscription system by myself.

Obviously, **Laravel Cashier** cannot be helpful, so I need some guides to follow. I don't have any idea about how it should be implemented.

For more detail, I'm gonna build a social-media scheduling service and my pricing is much like http://busy.io/pricing, but a little bit different.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to make a system on which you can transfer money into your account before you run out of money.

We in the Netherlands have also a system that is widely used voor internet banking (iDeal). You can only transfor money once with it. Not for a subcription-like monthly payment.

I guess that there will be something similar available for you.

One downside: when you are storing other people's balance in your own database, security is a VERY IMPORTANT thing to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Of course in Iran, we do have online billing system and users can pay online and in this case, everything will be handled by that payment website (It's called Pay.ir). So we don't have any problem in online billing.
I'm just looking for a way to implement monthly subscription system for my project. I don't know what is the best way to build it. Should I store my plans in Database or in Code? Or something else?
So confused!

Comment: Depends. Do you want to manage your plans as an administrator or are they always the same. What you generally want to do is making a column `subscription_type` and a `subscription_ends_at`date column. When someone pays. You can set that date to +1month or so. And send them a reminder when they have to pay again. Something like that

Comment: No, I don't think so. It will be static but maybe in the future, because of marketing strategy I change the price or scheduling limitation. I stored plans information in a config file and also I have a `licenses` table which will store `plan_id`, `user_id` and other information about the user's subscription status. Furthermore, I set a middleware to check user subscription status for each request. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. The only important thing left to do is to make sure the plans expire on their own. With something like a `expires_on` column. Because then their subscription will end automatically without any code. Then you add `where('expires_at', Carbon::now())` somewhere in your middleware. When it is expired you give them maybe the opportunity to renew their subscription. I think that you are on a good path here.

Comment: I do have `created_at` and `expires_at` fields in my `licenses` table but it does not make sense to me to check and compare the same date on every request with Middleware. I think a better way should exist.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think there is a better way. You HAVE to check every request if the user is valid.  And a date comparison is the best way to do it. Most of the time you already load the logged in user for displaying profile information. So it shouldn't cost you an extra database query

Comment: Thank you so much. So I'll implement it as I designed before.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bpuig/laravel-subby

I'm sharing an updated repo since the one mentioned by Fernando is abandoned.
This one is also a fork from the abandoned one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem has you.
Sorry to be 4 years and 8 months later, but next time try this https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-subscriptions.
Is a package to manage subscriptions and you can use your loved payment gateway. This will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: This package is now abandoned